# Store the user input to parallel arrayin C#

Tags: c#

i am trying to give the user 2 options one is to see what the array stored, and the second option is to enter the new items. Any help please! I have tried to add the array in the method ItemInfo() but it doesn't work as well, i have tried to do like this in switch:

```
ItemInfo(itemNArr[itemN],itemNameArr[itemName],itemPriceArr[itemPrice],itemStockArr[itemNStock],itemRatingArr[itemRating]
```

but still does not work as well. So what i should do in this case to pass the user input to the array and store it!? I will appreciate the help.

The problem that i got is:

```
The name 'itemN' does not exist in the current context line 37
The name 'itemName' does not exist in the current context line 37
The name 'itemPrice' does not exist in the current context line 37
The name 'itemNStock' does not exist in the current context line 37
The name 'itemRating' does not exist in the current context line 37
```

And the code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using static System.Console;
namespace program
    {
        class UseItem
        {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int item = AppIntro();
            string[] itemNArr = new string[item];
            string[] itemNameArr = new string[item];
            double[] itemPriceArr = new double[item];
            int[] itemStockArr = new int[item];
            int[] itemRateArr = new int[item];
            // ask to enter price for produect
            for (int i = 0; i < item; i++)
            {
                Clear();
                ItemInfo(i,  out itemNameArr[i], out itemPriceArr[i],  itemStockArr[i],  itemRateArr[i]);
                Clear();
            }
            string ans;
            do
            {
                WriteLine("What would you like to do next?");
                WriteLine(" Enter 1 to display individual course" + " and 2 to add a new product");
                int option = int.Parse(ReadLine());
                int result = int.Parse(ReadLine());
                switch (option)
                {
                    case 1:
                        DisplayItems(itemNArr,itemNameArr,itemPriceArr, itemStockArr, itemRateArr);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        result = ItemInfo(itemN, itemName,itemPrice,itemNStock,itemRating);
                        break;
                    default:
                        WriteLine("No valid entery was entered. " + "i decided to exit the application.... ");
                        break;
                }
                WriteLine("\n\nWould you like to do another operation?");
                ans = ReadLine();
            } while (ans == "Yes" || ans == "yes");
            WriteLine("\n\nThank you for choosing our application.... coma back again :) ");
        }
            public static int AppIntro()
            {
            WriteLine("Welcome to the PSO App: ");
            WriteLine("You will be asked to enter the product name" + " product price, how many you have in stock of the product" + " and the rate of the product");
            WriteLine("Then you will have a choise to display individual product" + "info");
            WriteLine("\n\nHow many products you want to add!?");
                return int.Parse(ReadLine());
            }
        public static void ItemInfo(int itemN, out string itemName, out double itemPrice, int itemNStock, int itemRating)
        {
            Write(" Enter the item number {0}:", itemN+1);
            itemName = ReadLine();
            Write(" Enter the item name: ");
            itemName = ReadLine();
            Write(" Enter the item price: ");
            itemPrice = double.Parse(ReadLine());
            Write(" Enter the number of the item in stock: ");
            itemNStock = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            Write(" Enter the rate of the item: ");
            itemRating = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        }
        public static void DisplayItems(string[]itemN, string[] itemName, double[] itemPrice, int[] itemNStock, int[] itemRating)
        {
            Write(" Which items would you like to display? Enter it's number: ");
            string valueIn = ReadLine();

            int n = 0;
            for(int i=0; i < itemN.Length; i++)
            {
                if(valueIn == itemN[i])
                {
                    n = i;
                }
                Clear();
                WriteLine("Your item info: ");
                WriteLine("item number is: " + itemN[n]);
                WriteLine("item name is: " + itemName[n]);
                WriteLine(" item price is: " + itemPrice[n]);
                WriteLine(" number of item in the stock is: " + itemNStock[n]);
                WriteLine(" item rate is: " + itemRating[n]);
            }
        }
            }

        }
```

Comment: I suggest you use the debugger and step through your code step by step to find the problem.  This looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: Next lesson: Introduction to custom classes

Comment: The error is telling you that those names are not defined within the context of the code (i.e. inside the `Main` method, where that line of code resides). You should probably just call `ItemInfo` as you did previously, in the `for` loop, by passing the array items as `out` parameters (using the numeric index of the item you want to modify). But note that you can't add new items to an array, you can only modify existing items. To modify the size of the array, you have to create a new array with the larger size and then move the existing items to it.

Comment: Also, don't feel bad about previous comments. We've all been exactly where you are. Learning to use the debugger will help immensely. And custom classes solve the problem of using multiple arrays to store properties values of similar objects.

Comment: @Skarali, I don't think the offense was intended. When itsme86 says "Next lesson: Introduction to custom classes", his tone may be playful but it's excellent advise and that usually _is_ the next lesson after one experiments with parallel arrays in order to understand the motivation for user-defined types.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for your respond and i agree with you but the two comments was hard for me while i was struggling you know. So again i sayd sorry for misunderstanding the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close to the answer and finally i want to say that here is the answer of my questions.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using static System.Console;
namespace program
    {
        class UseItem
        {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 0;
            int item = AppIntro();
           
            string[] itemNArr = new string[item];
            string[] itemNameArr = new string[item];
            double[] itemPriceArr = new double[item];
            int[] itemStockArr = new int[item];
            int[] itemRateArr = new int[item];
            // ask to enter price for produect
            //for (int i = 0; i < item; i++)
            //{
            //Clear();
            n = ItemInfo(n, itemNArr, itemNameArr, itemPriceArr, itemStockArr, itemRateArr);
            //Clear();
            //}
            string ans;
            do
            {
               // WriteLine("What would you like to do next?");
                WriteLine(" Enter 1 to display individual course" + " and 2 to add a new product");
                int option = int.Parse(ReadLine());
                //int result = int.Parse(ReadLine());
                
                switch (option)
                {
                    case 1:
                        DisplayItems(itemNArr,itemNameArr,itemPriceArr, itemStockArr, itemRateArr);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        n = ItemInfo(n, itemNArr, itemNameArr, itemPriceArr, itemStockArr, itemRateArr);
                        break;
                    default:
                        WriteLine("No valid entery was entered. " + "i decided to exit the application.... ");
                        break;
                }
                WriteLine("\n\nWould you like to do another operation?");
                ans = ReadLine();
            } while (ans == "Yes" || ans == "yes");
            WriteLine("\n\nThank you for choosing our application.... come back again :) ");
        }
            public static int AppIntro()
            {
            WriteLine("Welcome to the PSO App: ");
            WriteLine("You will be asked to enter the product name" + " product price, how many you have in stock of the product" + " and the rate of the product");
            WriteLine("Then you will have a choise to display individual product" + "info");
            WriteLine("\n\nHow many products you want to add!?");
            return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        public static int ItemInfo(int n, string[] itemN, string[] itemName, double[] itemPrice, int[] itemNStock, int[] itemRating)
        {


                Write(" Enter the item number:");
            itemN[n] = ReadLine();
                Write(" Enter the item name: ");
            itemName[n] = ReadLine();

            Write(" Enter the item price: ");
            itemPrice[n] = double.Parse(ReadLine());
                Write(" Enter the number of the item in stock: ");
            itemNStock[n] = int.Parse(ReadLine());
                Write(" Enter the rate of the item: ");
            itemRating[n] = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            n++;
            return n;
        }
        public static void DisplayItems(string[]itemN, string[] itemName, double[] itemPrice, int[] itemNStock, int[] itemRating)
        {
            Write(" Which items would you like to display? Enter it's number: ");
            string valueIn = ReadLine();

            int n = 0;
            for(int i=0; i < itemN.Length; i++)
            {
                if(valueIn == itemN[i])
                {
                    n = i;
                }
                Clear();
                WriteLine("Your item info: ");
                WriteLine("item number is: " + itemN[n]);
                WriteLine("item name is: " + itemName[n]);
                WriteLine(" item price is: " + itemPrice[n]);
                WriteLine(" number of item in the stock is: " + itemNStock[n]);
                WriteLine(" item rate is: " + itemRating[n]);
            }
        }
            }

        }
```